# How to make some text in array responds to the user touch to open a new activity?

Tags: java, android

So i have a TextView Array, Let's just say:

```
TextView[] allTV = new TextView[sizeOfTheAray];
```

and i already fill in the array using this :

```
for(int i = 0;i<allTV.length;i++){
  allTV[i]= new TextView(getApplicationContext());
  allTV[i].setText("Hello there");
}
```

So what i want to do is, when I click a particular textview, it will open a new activity(each textview has different activity that is reffered to).

p.s. my class is already implements View.OnClickListener

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So then, what is the problem? I mean you shouldn't be using the Application context(use the current Activity context), you should ensure the TextViews are clickable by explicitly making them so, but you haven't given us an actual problem to solve.

Comment: add each TextView in a layout

Answer (score 0):

set the id of each text view and take a activity array relatively to text view id 
and in on click listener cast the view as text view then get view id and open relative activity